# How can I add button with row span in ag-grid in Angular

Tags: angular, button, html-table, ag-grid

I have used ag-grid in my project. Now I used cell renderer to display button in "action" column,
it's working fine (button is displayed on each row, also works when clicked).

For second task I want to put [button with row span, as show in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0N8w.png)

Above image is just a reference type. (it has no rowspan).
What exactly i want is in this
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEstJ.png)

Comment: Hey, consider adding some code to your question to help people solve your problem. You can read about good practises here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it would be great if you can share some code showing what work you did to solve this problem and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see row span in your attached image, But you can easily add `rowSpan` property to your `columnDefs` object see more [HERE](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-spanning/) ( or adding `colSpan` like [THIS](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-spanning/) )

And if you want to just display two or more buttons in a single column ( as I see in your image) You can add them in your cell renderer component.

**UPDATE:**

Example for calculating cars length to return row span value:

```
colDef = {
    headerName: "Country",
    field: "country",
    rowSpan: function(params) {
        return params.data.cars.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but let me edit the question so you can understand more about what i want.

Comment: The links you have shared, they already know that if there is value "Russia" then use rowspan, or if there's a athlete with name Ryan then use rowsapn.                                   But for my issue i dont know if user have one car or four (shown in new image on my post).

Comment: You can use a function to calculate cars length for row span value like above.
If you share some of your code that you have tried, then I can better help you